# How to cite an IEEE conference paper properly

Tags: bibtex, ieeeconf

I want to cite a conference paper that I found on IEEE, the following details I listed below are already mentioned in the IEEE website.

```
@inproceedings{cite5,
author = "Wen-Yang Chang ; Bo-Yao Hsu ; Jia-Wei Hsu",
title = "{Real-Time Collision Avoidance for Five-Axis CNC Machine Tool Based on Cyber-Physical System}",
booktitle= {2018 IEEE International Conference on Advanced Manufacturing (ICAM)},
address={Yunlin, Taiwan},
month= Jan,
year="2019",
pages="4" }
```

but in the paper itself there other details like the University name, the Research Center... Now I'm not sure if I cited it properly or not

**Real-Time Collision Avoidance for Five-Axis CNC Machine Tool Based on CyberPhysical System**

Wen-Yang Chang1,*, Bo-Yao Hsu2,*, Jia-Wei Hsu2
1,

1,*Department of Mechanical and Computer-Aided Engineering, National Formosa University 1
Smart Machine and Intelligent Manufacturing Research Center, National Formosa University 2
Department of Power Mechanical Engineering, National Formosa University
No.64, Wunhua Rd.

Huwei Township, Yunlin County 632, Taiwan
1,*wenyang@nfu.edu.tw, 2,*d0775102@gm.nfu.edu.tw

If there is a rule to follow please tell me.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: It is uncommon to include affiliations in citations, you should be fine there. On a TeXnical note, note that names *must* be separated with the keyword `and` regardless of the desired output, so *`author = "Wen-Yang Chang ; Bo-Yao Hsu ; Jia-Wei Hsu",` should be `author = {Wen-Yang Chang and Bo-Yao Hsu and Jia-Wei Hsu},` (it does not matter whether you use `"..."` or `{...}` as field delimiters, but I strongly prefer and thus always use `{...}`). ...

Comment: ... I'd also avoid the WYSIWYG curly braces in `title = "{Real-Time Collision Avoidance for Five-Axis CNC Machine Tool Based on Cyber-Physical System}",` that stop the case changing functions from doing their work, `title = {Real-Time Collision Avoidance for Five-Axis {CNC} Machine Tool Based on Cyber-Physical System},` would be nicer.

Comment: @Mico I'm using the plain style , it is for a master thesis

Comment: @moewe you're right ! it is a lot nicer thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `author` field of the bibliographic entry, which I understand you obtained from some website, is definitely in error.

```
author = "Wen-Yang Chang ; Bo-Yao Hsu ; Jia-Wei Hsu",
```

is wrong because it use semicolons instead of the keyword `and` to separate the authors' names. The field really has to be

```
author = "Wen-Yang Chang and Bo-Yao Hsu and Jia-Wei Hsu",
```

The `pages` field also doesn't look right. Sure enough, instead of `pages = 4,`, it should be `pages = {284-287},`.

I would also encase the acronym CNC in a pair of curly braces in order to keep BibTeX from converting it to lowercase letters.

On the other hand, there is *absolutely no need* to list the authors' current academic affiliations, their physical addresses, or their email addresses. The point of providing bibliographic references is to provide enough information for readers to figure out how to go about obtaining copies of the publications they're interested in. It serves little to no known purpose to list the authors' current affiliations in a bibliographic entry -- the more so as these pieces of information may be, and likely will be, obsolete within a few short years. In contrast, the authors' names and the title of publication are *not* subject to this type of obsolescence, are they?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{chang-hsu-hsu:18,
author= {Chang, Wen-Yang and Hsu, Bo-Yao and Hsu, Jia-Wei},
year  = {2018},
pages = {284--287},
title = {Real-Time Collision Avoidance for Five-Axis {CNC} 
         Machine Tool Based on Cyber-Physical System},
booktitle= {2018 IEEE International Conference on Advanced Manufacturing (ICAM)},
address={Yunlin, Taiwan},
doi   = {10.1109/AMCON.2018.8615042}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\nocite{chang-hsu-hsu:18}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited it and it looks much reasonable now, Thank you